# Localizing Chrome Hosted App Urls

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, hosted-app

I'm attempting to localize a chrome hosted app that uses the Drive SDK and it's not obvious how to route people to a custom URL based on the locale. Within `manifest.json` I want to put the locale in my `app.launch.web_url` so once a user lands on my site the correct locale is loaded. I've tried

```
"app": {
      "launch": {
         "web_url": "__MSG_launchUrl__"
      }
   },
```

and

```
"app": {
      "launch": {
         "web_url": "http://www.foo.com/__MSG_locale__/endpoint"
      }
   },
```

but the first throws an error when you try to upload it because Google isn't pulling the string from the `messages.json` file. The second fails because although it gets past Google's validator, it interprets `__MSG_launchUrl__` as a literal string instead of a lookup variable.

On a similar note, I don't see a way to specify a locale specific url within the Google Drive SDK settings either.

Comment: How is that an *extension*? What you present is a hosted app. I don't think they support `chrome.i18n`. I've edited your question.

Comment: Ok yes this particular case is for an app instead of an extension but the semantics for the webstore listing are the same: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#details

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this (the first failure) should be [reported to Google](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/) as a Web Store problem.

The second method is not supported by the i18n mechanism.

Obviously, the app still needs to be tied to a single verified domain, but it should pass checks if all locales match that domain.

Comment: I played with it some more and you can actually do something like `https://www.foo.com/__MSG_@@ui_locale__/endpoint` however that too is bugged since it seems to always resolve to `en_US` regardless of the language you were using when installing and via the chrome apps launcher when the default language is something other than `en_US`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Accepts-Language` header sent to the server when the app is launched to localize your application.